# Отправка сообщений Telegram-ботом всем пользователям в определенное время

Tags: python, telegram-bot, flask, telebot

Есть Telegram-бот (`pyTelegramBotAPI`), запущенный на PythonAnywhere (`Flask`), он умеет реагировать на определенные команды. Возможно ли дополнительно к этому реализовать периодическую отправку сообщений всем пользователям в определенное время?

У меня так и не получилось найти инструкций по этому вопросу. Встречал иногда упоминания библиотеки `schedule`, но встроить ее в PythonAnywhere не вышло, так как там работает только 1 поток.

Comment: Если с английским всё норм, то можно здесь почитать https://www.pythoncircle.com/post/50/how-to-schedule-a-cron-on-pythonanywhere-server/

Comment: Если я правильно понял, надо создать ещё один скрипт, который shedule как сказал @svstnv

Answer (score 0):

Используйте модуль datetime. Через него получаете время, проверяете то ли это время, отсылает, если все ок. Что отослать всем используйте цикл по пользователям.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, я не могу просто взять и начать проверять то ли сейчас время посреди работы веб-приложения.

Comment: Извините, я невнимательно прочитал, получается.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать библитеку aiocron и сделать hendler.Пример для повторение каждую минуту @aiocron.crontab('*/1 * * * *')